migrate old application Seam/Jboss5 into Spring Java17Tomcat 10 - Better mode for redo
I must migrate an old application running in JBoss5, writed in java5 with frame SeamJboss (an old sum of jsf and ejb in a single framework).
the new environment is Tomcat10, OpenIdk17.  I may valuate if is a good choice migrate in Spring framework e how reuse the most code as possible (million of rows).
The ratio is that CDI is now implemented in Spring (and in EE too) e rewrite EJB in SpringBean.
The most code is in the logic (controller) and not in configuration, so I can rewrite some parts of config code.
Secondary is the GUI parts. The best solution per Spring ?
thak you very much - tenente
